# How to change the array elements proprity in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Array Proprity]

I am adding the new task using following javascript code:

```
  function addTask(name, important){
    alert(important);
    const newTask = {id: "todo" + nanoid(), name:name, completed:false, important:important, checked:false};
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
    console.log(setTasks)
  }
```

Now, I would like to add the last task on the first place of the application. May I ask please how to make it possible?

Comment: Try `setTasks([newTask, ...tasks]);`

Comment: use `unshift()`

Comment: @JonesJoseph, could you please elaborate?

Comment: `tasks.unshift(newTask)` - the method adds the given element to the beginning of the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: @RameshReddy, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTasks([newTask, ...tasks]);
```

Is the cleanest way to add items in front, however later on it may prove inconsistent (after saving into db for example and retrieving the list from db), personally I would use array.sort() method and sort the array by creation date or / and by "important" key. This way, no matter how you push an item into array, they will be always in correct / needed order.